# The "uncovered area in the survey" or the under covered area in the survey

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality, synonyms

I sampled the **soil quality over a wide region**. However, some areas in my study area were not sampled in this survey. So, I'm wondering how can I address these areas:

> A) the uncovered areas in the survey
>   B) the under-covered areas
>   C) non-covered areas

Or there is another suitable term for this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Areas not covered.

Answer (score -1):

As in:

*However, some areas in my study area were **unsampled** (or **not covered**).*

**unsampled**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/217489?redirectedFrom=un-sampled#eid)

> Untried; not experienced.